# Deploying project to Heroku builds fine but is unable to release and generates the SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty error

Tags: django, heroku

I am new to Django and Heroku. I cloned t[his][1] project from Github and tried to push it to Heroku. The entire build process goes smoothly, but the project never gets released. Unfortunately as soon as I get to the release stage  I keep running into this error and have no idea how to solve it. Any suggestions?

```
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):

remote:   File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
remote:     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
remote:     utility.execute()
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
remote:     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 224, in fetch_comman
remote:     klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 36, in load_command_class
remote:     module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
remote:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 14, in <module>
remote:     from django.db.migrations.autodetector import MigrationAutodetector
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 11, in <module>
remote:     from django.db.migrations.questioner import MigrationQuestioner
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/questioner.py", line 9, in <module>
remote:     from .loader import MigrationLoader
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 8, in <module>
remote:     from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 9, in <module>
remote:     class MigrationRecorder:
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 22, in MigrationRecorder
remote:     class Migration(models.Model):
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 87, in __new__
remote:     app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 249, in get_containing_app_config
remote:     self.check_apps_ready()
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 131, in check_apps_ready
remote:     settings.INSTALLED_APPS
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
remote:     self._setup(name)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
remote:     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 126, in __init__
remote:     raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
remote: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
remote: Waiting for release... failed.


  [1]: https://github.com/pau-not-paul/memrise-clone-react-djangohttps://
```

Comment: could you check the secret_key under settings.py? is the format secret_key="KEY"?

Comment: The format is SECRET_KEY= 'KEY'